# HTML Form not submitted with select2

Tags: jquery-select2

I have been trying to use select 2 from:

ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Not sure why the form  is not submitted when I try to submit it. Not getting any error on browser error logs also.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Form Submit</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/jsc.css">
    <link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="select2.js"></script>
            <script>
               $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#e1").select2({
                               formatResult: format,
                               formatSelection: format,
                               minimumResultsForSearch: 15,
                               escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
                });

               }
               );

                function format(state) {
                   if (!state.id) return state.text; // optgroup
                   return "<img class='flag' src='images/flags/1.gif'/>" + state.text;
                   }

        </script>
</head>
<body >
    <h1>JavaScript Form Submit Example</h1>
        <form id="myform" action="https://www.google.com" method="get" name="myform" onsubmit="return false;" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            Select a state:
            <select id="e1">
                            <option value="app">Apple</option>
                            <option value="ball">Ball</option>
            </select>
        <a href="javascript:void();">Submit</a>
        </form>
 </html>
```

Comment: Does Select2 let you submit a form simply by creating a link?  seems to me you should try it with an `<input type='submit'>` instead of the link that says "Submit" but doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: You get no error because there's not a syntax error - just a logic one. As stated above, you never actually submit the form. `javascript:void();` just does nothing.